# Condense repetitive jQuery .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a better way of writing this repetitive jQuery function:

```
(function($) {
  var mobileAmount = 300;

  $('#_100').click(function() {
    $('*').removeClass('-amount-active');
    $('#_100').addClass('-amount-active');
    mobileAmount = 100;
  });
  $('#_200').click(function() {
    $('*').removeClass('-amount-active');
    $('#_200').addClass('-amount-active');
    mobileAmount = 200;
  });
  $('#_300').click(function() {
    $('*').removeClass('-amount-active');
    $('#_300').addClass('-amount-active');
    mobileAmount = 300;
  });

  ...

})( jQuery );
```

There is a number of amount buttons and each time one is clicked it receives the active class for styling and updates the mobileAmount variable.

Comment: Well the info is a bit succinct, however it seems that the amount is a decisive factor, so either loop the possible different amounts per 100 or find a shared selector and read the amount from the selectors `id` attribute. I think however that the question itself is not really on-topic (cfr: [help/on-topic])

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish with this code, and make that the title of the question. (See [ask].) Ideally, you should include a demonstration (press Ctrl-M in the question editor). We could give you much better advice if you provide the full context. I suspect that code repetitiveness should not be your primary concern here — you probably have other issues like flexibility and correctness that you should worry about more.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Fortunately Sintu came up with just what I was after but I will keep this in mind when asking future questions. Is it still worth trying to improve the question or should I leave it now that it's been answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to fix this:

- Add class 'amount-button' to all buttons
- Add attribute data-mobileamount to all buttons and assign values like
  100, 200, .. to each button.

For example:
<button class="amount-button" data-mobileamount="100" >Mobile Amount 100</button >
<button class="amount-button" data-mobileamount="200">Mobile Amount 200</button>

```
 (function($) {
  var mobileAmount = 300;
  $('.amount-button').click(function() {
    $('*').removeClass('-amount-active');
    $(this).addClass('-amount-active');
    mobileAmount = $(this).data('mobileamount');
  });
})( jQuery );
```